# Scaling two items

Tags: java, javascript, math, svg

Imagine I have two boxes, one(A) has the following dimensions: width = 120, height = 80 and the other(B) has width = 300 and height 120. Using the above values, how would I scale A to B's dimensions while maintaining either the width or height of B. I want to maintain either of them. I have been stuck on this problem and I am not very good with Math. Any help would be appreciated.

Question: Does this require the use of an aspect ratio?

Comment: Its not exactly clear what you are trying to do here. Do you want to animate a resize of box A to the size of Box B?

Comment: No animation just a formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to maintain A's aspect ratio, or not?

- Scaling A (120, 80) to B's *width* would give (300, (300/120)*80) = (300, 200).
- Scaling A (120, 80) to B's *height* would give ((120/80)*120, 120) = (180, 120).

The formulas are:

```
Scaling Factor = Intended Measurement/ Original Measurement
Scaled Measurement = Original Measurement * Scaling Factor
```

If you don't care about aspect ratios at all, then you'd just end up using B box's size in both dimensions; eg (300, 120). But you probably do want to preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: Could A be made to mimic B's aspect ratio?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. The example Thomas W gave should work.